# What should the Z coordinate be after transformed by the projection matrix?

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation

I'm working on an OpenGL 1.x implementation for the Sega Dreamcast. Because the Dreamcast didn't have any hardware T&L the entire vertex transformation pipeline has to be done in software.

What also has to be done in software is clipping to the near-Z plane as failure to clip results in the polygon being dropped entirely from rendering by the hardware.

I'm having some trouble getting the transform -> clip -> perspective divide process working correctly and basically I can sum up the problem as follows:

- I transform polygon vertices by the modelview and projection matrices
- I clip each polygon against the W = 0.000001 plane
- This results in new vertices on the near plane with a W of 0.000001, but a Z which is *twice the near plane distance*
- At perspective divide vertex.z /= vertex.w results in an extreme value because we're dividing a Z value (e.g. 0.2) by 0.000001

Something seems very wrong here. The projection matrix is being generated in the same way as described in the [glFrustum docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFrustum.xml).

So my question is, if I have a coordinate on the near plane, should its Z value be zero after transform by the projection matrix or should it be the near-z distance, or something else?

After clipping polygons to the W = 0.000001 plane, should the generated Z coordinates be -0.000001?

*Update:*

Here is the projection matrix as calculated by: `gluPerspective(45.0f, 640.0f / 480.0f, 0.44f, 100.0f);`

```
1.810660 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 2.414213 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 -1.008839 -0.883889
0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
```

Does this look correct? It's the value in the right-hand column I'm not sure about...

Comment: https://www.gamedevs.org/uploads/fast-extraction-viewing-frustum-planes-from-world-view-projection-matrix.pdf I think this may help nudge you along

Answer (score 1):

Well that looks right to me. your projection matrix should be bringing you into normalized device coordinates which range from [-1,1], correct? [The Z value should represent your depth and is used by the depth buffer, if I'm not mistaken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902574/is-the-projection-matrix-in-opengl-really-a-projection-matrix). If you're in 2D using 4x4 matrices, I would imagine you should expect to see 0 in every Z output, as that zero should cancel out any final results, and if you aren't then I would certainly track down where that Z value is creeping from.

https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix